# How to find a call path from current function to another in VS Code (similar to Alleycat plugin for IDA Pro)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, call-hierarchy

In VS Code, there are classic commands like 'Show Call Hierarchy', 'Find All References', but there is no command to find a call path from Function A to Function B. In IDA Pro, there is a plugin called [Alleycat](https://github.com/fireundubh/IDA7-Alleycat) who can do this.

How can I find a call path from Function A to Function B? Is there any extension to do so?